# How to create a new instance of an NSDocument with NSDocumentController?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdocument, nsdocumentcontroller

I tried

```
[[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] duplicateDocumentWithContentsOfURL:nil
                                                                            copying:NO
                                                                        displayName:nil
                                                                              error:NULL] ;
```

but it is not working. I have the error

```
typeForContentsOfURL:error: must be overridden for your application to support non-'file:' URLs.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try like this below:-

```
   [[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController]newDocument:self];
```

Comment: Thanks !! I was looking for the wrong keyword : `create` instead of `new` !!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know about the `NSDocument+NSDocumentController` machinery but here is my guess . Since I am answering my own question, please don't hesitate to comment or react.

```
    [[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] addDocument:[[Document alloc] initWithType:nil
                                                                                      error:NULL]] ;
```